# How to handle prototype chaining with browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, browserify

I have JavaScript files like this:

shape.js

```
    var shape = (function() {
        var shape = {};
        Object.defineProperty(shape, 'init', {
            value: function(x, y) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                return this;
            }
        });
        return shape;
    }());
```

circle.js

```
    var circle = (function(parent) {
        var circle = Object.create(parent);
        Object.defineProperty(circle, 'init', {
            value: function(x, y, r) {
                parent.init.call(this, x, y);
                this.r = r;
                return this;
            }
        });
        return circle;
    }(shape));
```

rectangle.js

```
    var rectangle = (function(parent) {
        var rectangle = Object.create(parent);
        Object.defineProperty(rectangle, 'init', {
            value: function(x, y, width, height) {
                parent.init.call(this, x, y);
                this.width = width;
                this.height = height;
                return this;
            }
        });
        return rectangle;
    }(shape));
```

rectangle-with-text.js

```
    var rectangleWithText = (function(parent) {
        var rectangleWithText = Object.create(parent);
        Object.defineProperty(rectangleWithText, 'init', {
            value: function(x, y, width, height, text) {
                parent.init.call(this, x, y, width, height);
                this.text = text;
                return this;
            }
        });
        return rectangleWithText;
    }(rectangle));
```

I also have other JavaScript files like constants.js, customErrors.js, validator.js, player.js, renderer.js, game.js, initializator.js, main.js in the same coding style.

Now I want to do some collision detection with [a simple JavaScript library for performing 2D collision detection](https://github.com/jriecken/sat-js) but I must type somewhere

```
    var SAT = require('sat');
```

I typed this in the global scope. (I know I am polluting the global scope with my shape, circle, rectangle etc. but I am still a junior and this is my best solution so far:)

The problem is that I must use browserify or some other similar framework which provides 'require', and I am not familiar with 'require' yet and how I must organize my code around it.

I installed browserify globaly and I also installed uniq in my project as well as sat (what I want indeed)

Now I believe I have to type a command like this:

browserify constants.js game-errors.js validator.js shape.js circle.js triangle.js rectangle.js rectangle-with-text.js player.js renderer.js game.js initializator.js main.js -o bundle.js

But when I reference bundle.js in my html file and I run the browser I get this errror in the console:

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: shape is not defined
```

which points to the code where I try to build circle, which means that my IIFE for the circle cannot see shape.

So what should I do in order to make browserify to build my bundle properly?

Comment: No, you don't need to organise your code around `require`. You've already organised it for high modularity. Everything you need to change are the first and the last line of each of your files, nothing else.

Comment: IIRC, browserify uses CommonJS-style module syntax. So you'd have to change `var … = (function(parent) {` to `module.exports = (function(parent) {` and change `}(…));` to `}(require("…"));`.

Comment: @Bergi, thank you very much! I fixed the code according to your advice and know it works and I think I start to understand the idea of module.exports and require('...');